# Is my code the best way to use async await?

Tags: javascript, express, async-await

**Am try to implement and learn `async await functions` in my login example, but I don't know if is the best, elegant and clean code. I have doubs meanly in catch errors, and if I need implement in a best way the const and functional programing. Can share your opinions?**

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {


    try {

        const { email } = req.body.email; // destructuring

        const usuarioEncontrado = await Usuario.findOne({email: email});

        // Validate user exist
        if (!usuarioEncontrado) { // when not exist return null
            throw res.status(404).json({error: 'El usuario no existe'});
        }

        // validate user pass
        if (!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, usuarioEncontrado.password)) {
            throw res.status(404).json({error: 'No match'});
        }

        const token = jwt.sign( // generate token
            {
                usuario: usuarioEncontrado 
            },
            SEED,
            {
                expiresIn: (60 * 60)
            }
        );

        res.status(200).json({ // send response
            token: token,
            usuario: usuarioEncontrado
        });

    } catch (e) { // send error

        res.status(404).json(e);

    }
}
```

**THANKS**

Comment: You're supposed to try something and ask a question if you have problems and you don't find any helpful answer

Comment: You're attempting to send double responses.  First you do `throw res.status(404).json(...)`.  Then, you catch that exception and do `res.status(404).json(e)` again.  That's not right.  If you're going to send the response, then just `return`, don't throw.  Or, just throw the exception without sending a response and send the actual error response from the `catch` handler.

Comment: Also, `throw res.status(404).json({error: 'No match'});` sends the response and then throws whatever `.json()` returns which is probably not what you want.  That won't be an error object of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows a couple problems:

1. You're attempting to send double responses. First you do throw `res.status(404).json(...)`. Then, you catch that exception and do `res.status(404).json(e)` again. That's not right. If you're going to send the response, then just return, don't throw. Or, just throw the exception without sending a response and send the actual error response from the catch handler.
2. Also, `throw res.status(404).json({error: 'No match'});` sends the response and then throws whatever `.json()` returns which is probably not what you want. That won't be an error object of any kind.

I prefer to centralize the places I send an error response to one place in the request handler.  That keeps you from ever attempting to send multiple responses and just makes the flow of the request handler easier to understand (in my opinion).

To do that, I just `throw` a custom error that may have a custom message/status associated with it and then catch all possible errors in one place.  Here's one way to do that.  The `myError` class can be used everywhere in your project, not specific to just one route.  The idea is that often when you `throw`, you know in that context what you want the status and message to be so you set that in the custom Error object and can then use that info in the catch.  The catch then has to determine whether it has your custom error or just a regular error.  First, I have a reusable Error subclass that lets me throw, not only a message, but also a status value.

```
// reusable error class that contains a status in addition to the message
class MyError extends Error {
    // this static method saves having to compare if it's a custom error object or not
    // every time we use this
    static sendError(res, e, status = 500) {
        if (e instanceof MyError) {
            e.sendError(res);
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(status);
        }
    }
    constructor(msg, status = 500) {
        // allow calling with or without new
        if (!(this instanceof MyError)) {
            return new MyError(msg, status);
        }
        super(msg);
        this.status = status;
    }
    sendError(res) {
        res.status(this.status).send(this.message);
    }
}
```

And, then here's how you use that in your code and centralize the sending of the error status.

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    try {

        const { email } = req.body.email; // destructuring

        const usuarioEncontrado = await Usuario.findOne({email: email});

        // Validate user exist
        if (!usuarioEncontrado) { // when not exist return null
            throw MyError('El usuario no existe', 404);
        }

        // validate user pass
        if (!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, usuarioEncontrado.password)) {
            throw MyError('No Match', 404);
        }

        const token = jwt.sign( // generate token
            {
                usuario: usuarioEncontrado 
            },
            SEED,
            {
                expiresIn: (60 * 60)
            }
        );

        res.status(200).json({ // send response
            token: token,
            usuario: usuarioEncontrado
        });

    } catch (e) { // log and send error response
        // e may be either MyError or some other system generated Error
        console.log(e);
        MyError.sendError(res, e);
    }
}
```